# How to implement multiple level merge in sap.m.Table?

Tags: sapui5

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gZuFyay7E2vFwNXqzvL3?p=preview)

I want to implement multiple level merge in sap.m.Table. I tried to add `mergeDuplicates="true"` in the second column, but it look like this:

[image]

Pretty strange. I added data of the first column to the second column: `<Text text="{name} {amount} "/>`, the split looks like want I want, but how to hide `{name}` data?

[image]

Did some research in [doc of sap.m.Column](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Column.html#getMergeFunctionName), find `mergeFunctionName`

> You can pass one string parameter to given function after "#" sign. e.g. "data#myparameter":

Can I pass both {name} and {amount} to `myparameter` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the root cause is that you should define your `sorter` properly for your binding.

```
items="{
        path: '/',
        sorter: [{
                   path: 'name', 
                   descending: false,
                   group:true
                 }, {
                   path: 'amount', 
                   descending: false,
                   group:true
                }]
       }"
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vaMRhvCYBsOAxcS9Lso7?p=preview  Still not working, if the amount data is all the same, the splitter of column 2 is still missing between "bus" and "truck".

Comment: @Tina, add group: true

Comment: added, still not working. Updated the demo. Did as doc says: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c4b2a32bb72f483faa173e890e48d812

Comment: @Tina which part is not working? http://plnkr.co/edit/jUHBsh7QoRWvLZhg9sow?p=preview

Comment: Sorry for putting `group:true` to the wrong place. I'm not sure whether our design will accept this work around. But there seems no other better solution. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

In order to create a property where we can add a property to hold such primary key that can automatically be accessed by a single getter function, we extend the Text control as shown below.

```js
sap.ui.define(
  ['sap/m/Text'],
  function(Text) {
    return Text.extend("namespace.controls.MergableText", {
      metadata: {
        properties: {
          mergeDependent: {
            type: "string",
            defaultValue: ""
          }
        }
      },
      renderer: function(oRm, oControl) {
        sap.m.TextRenderer.render(oRm, oControl); //use supercass renderer routine
      }
    });
  }
);
```

The above is a file called MergableText.js which can be stored in the controls folder in the webapp. Now this can be used by defining in namespace:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:custom="namespace.controls"
controllerName="namespace.controller.PlannedOT">
        <Table>
                <columns>....</columns>
                <items>
                        <ColumnListItem>
                                ....
                                <custom:MergableText text="{>amount}" mergeDependent="{name}">                                          </custom:MergableText>
                                ..... 
                        <ColumnListItem>
                </items>
        </Table>
</mvc:View>
```

In this manner the amount can be merged only based on its dependency on the name.

Answer (score 0):

Using mergeNameFunction is the good approach :) You can use any binding internal method that will force the comparison.

E.g.

```
<Column mergeDuplicates="true" mergeFunctionName="getBindingContext">
    <Text text="column2"/>
</Column>
```

will work with no other modifications

Comment: Tried it, seems not working. I want column 2 to merge: http://plnkr.co/edit/gZuFyay7E2vFwNXqzvL3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Late reply but hopefully still useful. I developed my own solution based on this.

Good news: What you want to achieve is possible without extending controls or grouping the table.

1. Add sap.ui.core library:

```
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
```

2. Add custom data to your cells like this:

```
<customData>
    <core:CustomData key="mergeKey" value="{name}" />
</customData>
```

3. Use this custom data in your merge function like this:

```
mergeFunctionName="data#mergeKey"
```

The magic happens when you use the binding from column1 and column2 combined as a value for the custom data in column 2. That stops the whole column2 from becoming one cell and you get the desired divider between bus and truck.

Final solution:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="demo.FirstPage"
    xmlns="sap.m"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:semantic="sap.f.semantic"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">

    <Table
        id="table"
        mode="MultiSelect"
        width="auto"
        items="{
            path: '/'
        }"
        growing="true"
        growingScrollToLoad="true">

        <columns>
            <Column
                mergeDuplicates="true"
                mergeFunctionName="data#mergeKey">
                    <Text text="column1"/>
            </Column>
            <Column
                mergeDuplicates="true"
                mergeFunctionName="data#mergeKey">
                    <Text text="column2"/>
            </Column>
            <Column>
                <Text text="column3"/>
            </Column>
        </columns>

        <items>
            <ColumnListItem id="cli" type="Detail">
                <cells>
                    <Text text="{name}">
                            <customData>
                                <core:CustomData key="mergeKey" value="{name}" />
                            </customData>
                    </Text>                 
                    <Text text="{amount}">
                            <customData>
                                <core:CustomData key="mergeKey" value="{name}{amount}" />
                            </customData>
                    </Text>                 
                    <Text text="{currency}, {size}"/>                   
                </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
        </items>
    </Table>
</mvc:View>
```

[Screenshot of final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoiCL.png)